# Convergence of an Interpolating Polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, lagrange-interpolation, numerical-calculus

Question: Let $$f(x)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\qquad -1\le x\le 1$$

Find out if this function is the limit of a sequence of interpolating polynomials $\{p_{4n}(x)\}$ of degree $\le 4n$ using the values of $f$ at the nodes $-2n,-2n+1,\ldots,2n$. Note that $f$ takes on values $\pm1$ and $0$ only at the nodes.

My attempt:

I have used here a theorem that gives the range of error when doing Lagrange interpolation. It says :

[image]

I say that since $(4n+1)$ is odd, so then $f^{(4n+1)}(\xi)=\pm\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{4n+1}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$.

But in any case, whether or not it's sine or cosine, as per the definition of $M_{4n+1}$, the value of $M_{4n+1}$ is $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{4n+1}$.

Then I argue that the limit of the maximum error as $n\to\infty$ is zero as per the following.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)!}\max_{x\in [-1,1]}|\pi_{4n+1}(x)|=0$$

And so eventually I infer that as $n\to\infty$, we do have a uniform convergence.

Am I correct in my reasoning? Also is there any significance of the statement in the question "$f$ takes on values $\pm1$ and $0$ only at the nodes" that I didn't take into account?

Comment: You need also a bound on $\pi_{4n+1}$. This will cancel to some degree the denominator. You could try to find out if the bound on $\pi_{4n+1}(x)$ on $[-n,n]$ is sufficiently smaller. Or explore convergence on a fixed interval $[-m,m]$, where for instance for $n>m^2$ you might get an easy to prove declining bound.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I made some corrections to the value of $M_{4n+1}$.  However, it seems the result doesn't change as in the limit of the first factor which is the fraction is zero and the second factor also becomes zero. The reason being as $n$ increases, the number of factors in that product increases and since the range of $x$ stays fixed, the maximum of that product would be zero. Correct?

Comment: For $|x|\le 1$ you get $|\pi_{4n+1}(x)|\le (2n)!(2n+1)!$, which grows slower by a factor of $4^{2n}$ than $(4n+1)!$. This should indeed be sufficient for convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\in[0,1]$ you get 
$$
|x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2n)|\le x(1-x)(2n)!
$$
and
$$
|(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+2n)|\le(2n+1)!
$$
The same can be done symmetrically for $x\in[-1,0]$.
This gives you as bound for the error of the interpolation polynomial
$$
\frac{(\frac\pi2)^{4n+1}(2n)!(2n+1)!}{(4n+1)!}|x|(1-|x|)
$$
Now apply some estimates for the factorials like $(\frac{k}3)^k\le k!\le (\frac{k}2)^k$ or the Stirling formulas to get
$$
\frac{(2n)!(2n+1)!}{(4n+1)!}\sim\frac{(2n)^{2n}(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{(4n+1)^{4n+1}}\sim 2^{-(4n+1)}.
$$
As $\frac\pi4<1$, this gives a geometric bound falling to zero for the error term for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: could you explain how you got the first and second inequalities?

Comment: $|x-k|=k-x\le k$ and on the negative side $|x-(-k)|=x+k\le k+1$ and then multiply this up.